# active job not saving data in the database rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

i want to save this message five time from active jobs not from controller.
is there anyway to that ?
here message.save just returning true and its not saving the message in databas.

```
class MessageBroadcastJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(message)
    for i in 0..5
      message.save!
      ActionCable.server.broadcast 'chat', {message: render_message(message)}
    end
  end

  private

  def render_message(message)
    MessagesController.render(
        partial: 'message',
        locals: {
            message: message
        }

    )
  end
end
```

this code is from model.

```
class Message < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  after_create_commit {
    MessageBroadcastJob.perform_later(self)
  }
end
```

Comment: 5 times save message? Why do you need that?

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling your job in code anywhere. You are saving that after_create_commit mean after saving message to active record you want to run this job. But you are not doing it.

So you have to save at least one time, to run this job. That mean in your controller or anywhere in code at least save once message, this job will run when you have saved message onces, than it will save message. If you still have issue please check job is running properly? do you have any configuration in redis

I smell from your codes you are using cable, that mean you have to put following in your conversation channel file.

```
Message.create(message_params)
```

As soon as above code run than your job will also run. If above all is good than you have also issue in your job, you are saying that same message should be saved, so it won't save 5 message, you have to take parameters in it do following

```
m = Message.new
m.body = message
m.user_id = message.user_id
# setup other parameters required
m.save
      ActionCable.server.broadcast 'chat', {message: render_message(message)}
```

Comment: i saved it once from controller but then i want this message to be saved to database 5 times from active job.
yes job is running properly.

Comment: modified reply, please change codes inside iteration.